# Complexity of finding the most likely edge

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, pr.probability

Consider a connected, unweighted, undirected graph $G$. Let $m$ be the number of edges and $n$ be the number of nodes.

Now consider the following random process. First sample a uniformly random spanning tree of $G$ and then pick an edge from this spanning tree uniformly at random. Our process returns the edge.

There is a probability distribution on edges implied by this process.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3781031/678546 points out that if $T$ is a uniform sampled spanning tree then

$$P(e \in T) = \mathscr{R}(e_- \leftrightarrow e_+)$$

where $e = \{e_-, e_+\}$ and $\mathscr{R}(a \leftrightarrow b)$ is the effective resistance between $a$ and $b$ when each edge is given resistance $1$.

Marcus M goes on to give a complexity of $O(mn^3)$ for computing the probabilities for every edge.  This is much too slow to run in practice for all but the smallest graphs.

If I only want to find an edge with the maximal probability, is there a faster algorithm? How about if I am happy with an approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with an approximation, then you can use approximate Laplacian solving, which takes time $\widetilde{O}(m)$. This is done explicitly in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0929) by Spielman and Srivastava, Theorem 2.

My guess is that this is optimal, even if you just want to determine the edge with maximal effective resistance.

Comment: Do you have to do this once per edge?

Comment: No. In $\widetilde{O}(m/\epsilon^2)$ time you can can construct a data structure, which then allows to $\epsilon$-approximate any effective resistance in time $\widetilde{O}(1)$ per edge.

Comment: Correction: in time $\widetilde{O}(1/\epsilon^2)$ per edge.

Comment: That is really a huge improvement. For an exact answer is the OPs complexity optimal?

Comment: (i) I clarified in the linked question of the OP that the actual time complexity is matrix multiplication time (so $O(n^{2.373})$ rather than $O(mn^3)$), (ii) my guess would be that this is optimal.